# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) (SCRAPY Shell)

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I ran this [URL](https://directory-service-dot-gweb-edu-activity-app.appspot.com/directory/search?expertTypes=trainer&query=&userPosition=31.170406299999996,%2072.7097161) with a `scrapy shell`. I tried to print the `JSON` response but it gave me an error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What could be the fix to it? appreciate your answers.

```
   scrapy shell https://directory-service-dot-gweb-edu-activity-app.appspot.com/directory/search?expertTypes=trainer&query=&userPosition=31.170406299999996,%2072.7097161
    
    >>> import json
    >>> print(json.loads(response.body))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the beginning of the file looks like:

```json
)]}',
{"partners": [],
...
```

which is not valid JSON. besides reporting this to the devs of the website, the only way I can figure out to fix it is to slice off the part in the beginning

```py
print(json.loads(response.body[6:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json
jd = json.dumps(response.text)
print(json.loads(jd))
```